# WM_QUERYENDSESSION is causing me problems

Tags: c#, wndproc

Making a simple application, so when the user logs out of Windows, it of course shuts the application down. We are making a simple USB Alert application which STOPS shutdown if a USB is detected when the user is logging off

This is the code so far.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private static int WM_QUERYENDSESSION = 0x11;
    private static bool systemShutdown = false;
    protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_QUERYENDSESSION)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("queryendsession: this is a logoff, shutdown, or reboot");
            systemShutdown = true;
            m.Result = (IntPtr)0;
        }

        // If this is WM_QUERYENDSESSION, the closing event should be
        // raised in the base WndProc.
        m.Result = (IntPtr)0;
        base.WndProc(ref m);

    } //WndProc 

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (systemShutdown)
        {
            systemShutdown = false;
            bool hasUSB = false;

            foreach (DriveInfo Drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
            {
                if (Drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
                {
                    hasUSB = true;
                }
            }

            if (hasUSB)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                MessageBox.Show("You still have USB device plugged in, please unplug it and log off again");
            }
            else
            {
                e.Cancel = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

What is happening is that the Windows Force Programs to Quit screen is being displayed, I read somewhere if you return 0 to WM_QUERYENDSESSION it does not display this, but it is still displaying this...

Any ideas?

EDIT:

We used the code that someone responded with, but we are still getting this screen.

[image: The screen we want to avoid!]

Comment: Is preventing the system from shutting down a good idea in the first place?

Comment: But we are building a program, that if a User has left a USB plugged it, they cannot shutdown or log off until they remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern bool AbortSystemShutdown(string lpMachineName);
```

Should abort the shutdown.

Comment: That is documented to work, also as others have said http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376877%28VS.85%29.aspx the ShutdownBlockReasonCreate() should also work.  The return code of 0 apparently died with vista.

Comment: I don't think the return code died with Vista.  I've been working on trying to support restarts from Windows from my modern C# Windows Forms App so it can save its progress to start back up after the reboot and if I let the base.wndProc handle the message or don't set m.Result = 0 then it will reboot regardless of the existence of a ShutdownBlockReasonCreate having been called.

Answer (score 3):

[This link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/06/14/10319617.aspx) is relevant.
It explains that you should use [Shutdown­Block­Reason­Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376877%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [Shutdown­Block­Reason­Destroy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376878%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I got this working fine now by adding this code in

```
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int CancelShutdown();
```

I also changed the header from WM_QUERYENDSESSION = 0x11; to WM_QUERYENDSESSION = 0x0011;

Not sure if this has done anything, but the code seems to work, Thanks to all the answers