# How to control power button press shutdown?

Tags: c#, winapi, wndproc, acpi, windows-7-embedded

I'm working on a kiosk style application where I need to control the shutdown/restart of the PC when the power button is pressed.  Thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242232/wm-queryendsession-is-causing-me-problems), I'm about 90% of the way there.

1. In control panel set the acpi power button press action to shutdown.
2. Listen for the WndProc message WM_QUERYENDSESSION
3. When received issue the completely undocumented:

   ```
   [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
   static extern int CancelShutdown();
   ```
4. Return from the WndProc and bring up my own message box asking the user to Shutdown / Restart or Cancel, and respond to their action.

Everything works well if I do a start / shutdown from the task bar (I can issue theses as fast as I want).  Everything also works well the first time I press the power button.  On subsequent power button presses though I see a minute or so delay before I receive the WM_QUERYENDSESSION message.

Is there a setting or registry entry about how often windows will issue an ACPI event?  I know it's not the hardware because under linux the same machine will fire the ACPI event as fast as I can press the button.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling in some favors at work, I was able to take this question directly to Microsoft support.    On my third support engineer, I was essentially told this is not possible at *an application level*.  It was his belief that calling the undocumented `CancelShutdown()` "confuses" the power manager or acpi driver which leads to the `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` message delay.  Since the `CancelShutdown()` is undocumented, MS is not willing investigate further.

So, how do you hook power button presses?  You need to write a device driver, specifically an [ACPI Filter Driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540493%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  We are investigating this now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible unless you speak with your hardware manufacturer or hardwire the start-button so that it doesn't send a signal to the hardware which handles this.
You can only delay it but even that would not give you 100% guarantee I guess.

Windows 8.1 will (maybe) bring a Kiosk Mode. Maybe that is what you are looking for ;-)

Comment: Please note that I'm not trying to hook the hardware shutdown that occurs if you hold down the power button.  I want the acpi event shutdown that occurs when you tap the button.  The OS is certainly able to hook that event and shutdown gracefully, why can't I?

Comment: Mark did you have any progress on this issue ? I having the same problem on windows 7 embedded.