# Windows shutdown cancellation timeout

Tags: c#

How we can extend the windows shutdown cancellation timeout?
If user initiated shutdown that time first I have to gracefully close my application then shutdown process resumes but not cancel after some time.

I have tried with registry keys but in won't work.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Are you trying to prevent shutdown?

Comment: [WM\_QUERYENDSESSION is causing me problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11242232)

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Windows Vista and moving forward Microsoft has seriously restricted the ability to block a shutdown because the user should be in charge of their machine. You can [request the user to cancel a shutdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-shutdownblockreasoncreate) by providing them with a prompt at the moment shutdown initiates. Generally its a good idea to create and destroy these immediately before and immediate after the operation that could harm the user's interests if their machine is shutdown during the operation.

Keep in mind, this is a prompt that will automatically terminate if the user takes no action. You cannot command a computer to not shutdown, you can give the user 5 seconds to reconsider their decision.